# PostAsJsonAsync fails when POCO class has [Required] attribute on int property

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, dotnet-httpclient

Using Web API and sending a POST using HttpClient. The code is as follows:

```
public class UserTransport
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  [Required]
  public string Name { get; set; }
  [Required]
  public int DepartmentId { get; set; }
}

var entity = new UserTransport() { Id = 1, Name = "bozo", DepartmentId = 1 };
var client = new HttpClient();
client.PostAsJsonAsync("http://myserver/Security/Edit", entity);
```

The call returns with a 500 Internal Server Error

However, if I remove the Required attribute on DepartmentId in UserTransport, it goes through no problem.

Any thoughts on why the Required attribute cannot be supported in this way? I'd like to make use of the attribute to define a custom error message on client side validation.